# What is the limit of this specific series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Anyone can give me the path for this, could not figure out which theory/method to use for this...
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1\cdot4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot7} + \frac{1}{7\cdot10}+.....+ \frac {1}{(3n-2)\cdot(3n+1)}\right)=?$$

Comment: Do partial fractions help here praps?

Comment: Note that $\frac{3}{(3n-2)\cdot (3n+1)}=\frac{1}{(3n-2)}-\frac{1}{(3n+1)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac1{1\times4}=\frac13\left(1-\frac14\right)$, $\displaystyle\frac1{4\times7}=\frac13\left(\frac14-\frac17\right)$, $\displaystyle\frac1{7\times10}=\frac13\left(\frac17-\frac1{10}\right)$, …

Answer (score 3):

If you break the terms in this way $$\frac{1}{(3n-2)(3n+1)}=\frac{1/3}{3n-2}-\frac{1/3}{3n+1}$$

many will cancel.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: It is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac13\left(
\frac11-\frac14+\frac14-\frac17+\frac17-\frac1{10}\ldots+\frac1{3n-2}-\frac1{3n+1}
\right)
$$